# rabbitmq source code compilation in windows

Tags: rabbitmq

I require to compile the rabbitmq source code in windows. I have downloaded the code from [path](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server) and installed **cygwin**.

As per the [link](https://www.rabbitmq.com/build-server.html), while performing **make** command, it is throwing below error:

> $ make
>       erlang.mk:4847: warning: overriding recipe for target '/cygdrive/d/Softwares/OSSSourceCode/rabbitmq-server-master/deps/syslog'
>       erlang.mk:4847: warning: ignoring old recipe for target '/cygdrive/d/Softwares/OSSSourceCode/rabbitmq-server-master/deps/syslog'
>        DEP    rabbit_common
>       /bin/sh: git: command not found
>       /bin/sh: git: command not found
>       /bin/sh: line 0: cd: /cygdrive/d/Softwares/OSSSourceCode/rabbitmq-server-master/deps/rabbit_common:
>   No such file or directory
>        DEP    rabbitmq_cli
>       /bin/sh: git: command not found
>       /bin/sh: git: command not found
>       /bin/sh: line 0: cd: /cygdrive/d/Softwares/OSSSourceCode/rabbitmq-server-master/deps/rabbitmq_cli:
>   No such file or directory
>       make: *** [erlang.mk:4851: /cygdrive/d/Softwares/OSSSourceCode/rabbitmq-server-master/deps/rabbitmq_cli]
>   Error 1

Please help me with this.

Comment: `git: command not found` you have to install git

Answer (score 0):

Compiling RabbitMQ on Windows is not recommended due to the complex steps required. If you must, here is a link to a guide to doing it:

https://gist.github.com/lukebakken/f0323f90291b5e5e7bbbe0287c411171